# how to flatten/penetrate an arbitrarily structured nested list in Python?

Tags: python, nested-lists, flatten

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

for instance, from:

```
[[1,2,3],'a',[[4],[5,6],7]]
```

we want to flatten/penetrate the structure and get all the elements at bottom listed in a line:

```
[1,2,3,'a',4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# a recursive function to flatten arbitrary nested lists into one simple 1D list
def flatten(inlist,outlist):   
    for e in inlist:
        if isinstance(e,list) :
            flatten(e,outlist)
        else:
            outlist.append(e)
```

it's a practice of recursive function, :). the "outlist" here serves as a reference for return-list.

there must be better structures...

;)
for example:

Comment: This is a case where recursion works well.

Comment: Btw, You should've included the "answer" as part of the question.

Comment: @Akvall: no, putting this as an answer is correct, since it answers the question!

Comment: @Eric, maybe it OK here, but typically people post their own solution in the question part, since they are looking for improvement.

Comment: @Akvall: Is the asker looking for improvement?

Comment: @Eric, I thought so..., but perhaps the winky smiley that I missed tells a different story.

Comment: is this an efficient way to flatten nested list?

Answer (score 0):

For your benefit, here is an implementation that modifies the list in-place:

```
def flatten_in_place(seq):
    if isinstance(seq, list):
        for index, item in reversed(list(enumerate(seq))):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                seq[index: index + 1] = fil(item)
        return seq
    else:
        return [seq]
```

Usage:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2], [3, 4], 5, 6, [7, [8, 9]]]
>>> flatten_in_place(l)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Interestingly enough, the timeit results (t = 1,000,000) show this to be slightly faster than your implementation:

```
flatten_in_place time: 4.88
flatten time: 5.16
```

I'm not sure why that is exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: I get an error on `fil` not being defined.

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've written this, but I believe `fil` is meant to be `flatten_in_place`. Will update this answer when I've had a chance to test it

Comment: Or, if you get a chance to test it, feel free to update it ;)